# OCaml type error (Variants/Pattern Matching)

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, variant

Trying to do a simple pattern matching with variants that will give me the in order concatenation of binary tree node strings, but getting an error in the recursive implementation:

```
type btnode =
  | Leaf
  | Node of string * btnode * btnode

let rec inorder bt = function
  | Leaf -> ""
  | Node(s, left, right) -> 
    (inorder left) ^ s ^ (inorder right)
  
let tree = inorder Node("a", Node("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
```

```
Error: This expression has type btnode -> string
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
let tree = inorder Node ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
```

Parses as:

```
let tree = inorder (Node) ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
```

You likely wanted:

```
let tree = inorder (Node ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf))
```

Or:

```
let tree = inorder @@ Node ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
```

However, you've also introduced an unnecessary parameter in your function:

```
let rec inorder bt = function
  | Leaf -> ""
  | Node(s, left, right) -> 
    (inorder left) ^ s ^ (inorder right)
```

The `bt` parameter is never used and unneeded.

```
let rec inorder = function
  | Leaf -> ""
  | Node(s, left, right) -> 
    (inorder left) ^ s ^ (inorder right)
```

Your error stems from this problem. `inorder left` and `inorder right` are seen as partial applications of `inorder` which yield a function which takes a `btnode` and returns a string. This results in a type mismatch when providing them to the `^` operator which has type `string -> string -> string`.

As an added (more advanced) note, if you can convert your binary tree into a sequence, then this becomes very straightforward using existing functions from the [`Seq` module](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html). And it becomes tail-recursive as an added bonus.

```
# let btnode_to_inorder_seq bt = 
    let rec aux bt stack () =
      match bt, stack with
      | Leaf, [] -> Seq.Nil
      | Leaf, x::xs -> aux x xs ()
      | Node (s, Leaf, Leaf), [] -> Seq.Cons (s, Seq.empty)
      | Node (s, Leaf, Leaf), x::xs -> Seq.Cons (s, aux x xs) 
      | Node (s, l, r), _ -> aux l (Node (s, Leaf, Leaf) :: r :: stack) ()
    in
    aux bt [];;
val btnode_to_inorder_seq : btnode -> string Seq.t = <fun>
# Node ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
  |> btnode_to_inorder_seq
  |> Seq.fold_left (^) "";;
- : string = "ba"
# Node ("a", Node ("b", Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)
  |> btnode_to_inorder_seq
  |> List.of_seq;;
- : string list = ["b"; "a"]
```